# How to active wrapper "udp" in php?

Tags: php, class, torrent

I am  heaving a class to handle torrent files from .torrent. Here is my class

```
class Torrent {

static public $errors = array();

/** Read and decode torrent file/data OR build a torrent from source folder/file(s)
 * Supported signatures:
 *  - Torrent( string $torrent );
 *  - Torrent( string $torrent, string $announce );
 *  - Torrent( string $torrent, array  $meta );
 *  - Torrent( string $file_or_folder );
 *  - Torrent( string $file_or_folder, string $announce_url, [int $piece_length] );
 *  - Torrent( string $file_or_folder, array $meta, [int $piece_length] );
 *  - Torrent( array $files_list );
 *  - Torrent( array $files_list, string $announce_url, [int $piece_length] );
 *  - Torrent( array $files_list, array $meta, [int $piece_length] );
 * @param string|array torrent to read or source folder/file(s)
 * @param string|array announce url or meta informations (optional)
 * @param int piece length (optional)
 */
public function __construct ( $data, $meta = array(), $piece_length = 256 ) 
{
    if ( $piece_length < 32 || $piece_length > 4096 ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid piece lenth, must be between 32 and 4096' ) );
    }
    if ( is_string( $meta ) ) {
        $meta =  array( 'announce' => $meta );
    }
    if ( $this->build( $data, $piece_length * 1024 ) ) {
        $this->touch();
    } else {
        $meta = array_merge( $meta, $this->decode( $data ) );
    }
    foreach( $meta as $key => $value ) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
}

/** Convert the current Torrent instance in torrent format
 * @return string encoded torrent data
 */
public function __toString() 
{
    return $this->encode( $this );
}

/** Return Errors
 * @return array|boolean error list or null if none
 */
public function errors() 
{
    return empty( self::$errors ) ? 
        false :
        self::$errors;
}

/**** Encode BitTorrent ****/

/** Encode torrent data
 * @param mixed data to encode
 * @return string torrent encoded data
 */
static protected function encode ( $mixed ) 
{
    switch ( gettype( $mixed ) ) {
        case 'integer':
        case 'double':
            return self::encode_integer( $mixed );
        case 'object':
            $mixed = (array) $mixed; //Bugfix by W-Shadow. Objects can't be ksort'ed anyway (see encode_array()).
        case 'array':
            return self::encode_array( $mixed );
        default:
            return self::encode_string( (string) $mixed );
    }
}

/** Encode torrent string
 * @param string string to encode
 * @return string encoded string
 */
static private function encode_string ( $string ) 
{
    return strlen( $string ) . ':' . $string;
}

/** Encode torrent integer
 * @param integer integer to encode
 * @return string encoded integer
 */
static private function encode_integer ( $integer ) 
{
    return 'i' . $integer . 'e';
}

/** Encode torrent dictionary or list
 * @param array array to encode
 * @return string encoded dictionary or list
 */
static private function encode_array ( $array ) 
{
    if ( self::is_list( (array) $array ) ) {
        $return = 'l';
        foreach ( $array as $value ) {
            $return .= self::encode( $value );
        }
    } else {
        ksort( $array, SORT_STRING );
        $return = 'd';
        foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
            $return .= self::encode( strval( $key ) ) . self::encode( $value );
        }
    }
    return $return . 'e';
}

/** Helper to test if an array is a list
 * @param array array to test
 * @return boolean is the array a list
 */
static protected function is_list ( $array ) 
{
    foreach ( array_keys( $array ) as $key ) {
        if ( ! is_int( $key ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**** Decode BitTorrent ****/

/** Decode torrent data or file
 * @param string data or file path to decode
 * @return array decoded torrent data
 */
static protected function decode ( $string ) 
{
    $data = is_file( $string ) ? 
        file_get_contents( $string ) :
        $string;
    return self::decode_data( $data );
}

/** Decode torrent data
 * @param string data to decode
 * @return array decoded torrent data
 */
static protected function decode_data ( & $data ) 
{
    switch( self::char( $data ) ) {
    case 'i':
        $data = substr( $data, 1 );
        return self::decode_integer( $data );
    case 'l':
        $data = substr( $data, 1 );
        return self::decode_list( $data );
    case 'd':
        $data = substr( $data, 1 );
        return self::decode_dictionary( $data );
    default:
        return self::decode_string( $data );
    }
}

/** Decode torrent dictionary
 * @param string data to decode
 * @return array decoded dictionary
 */
static private function decode_dictionary ( & $data ) 
{
    $dictionary = array();
    $previous = null;
    while ( ( $char = self::char( $data ) ) != 'e' ) {
        if ( $char === false ) {
            throw new Exception( __( 'Unterminated dictionary' ) );
        }
        if ( ! ctype_digit( $char ) ) {
            throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid dictionary key' ) );
        }
        $key = self::decode_string( $data );
        if ( isset( $dictionary[$key] ) ) {
            throw new Exception( __( 'Duplicate dictionary key' ) );
        }
        if ( $key < $previous ) {
            throw new Exception( __( 'Missorted dictionary key' ) );
        }
        $dictionary[$key] = self::decode_data( $data );
        $previous = $key;
    }
    $data = substr( $data, 1 );
    return $dictionary;
}

/** Decode torrent list
 * @param string data to decode
 * @return array decoded list
 */
static private function decode_list ( & $data ) 
{
    $list = array();
    while ( ( $char = self::char( $data ) ) != 'e' ) {
        if ( $char === false )  {
            throw new Exception( 'Unterminated list' );
        }
        $list[] = self::decode_data( $data );
    }
    $data = substr( $data, 1 );
    return $list;
}

/** Decode torrent string
 * @param string data to decode
 * @return string decoded string
 */
static private function decode_string ( & $data ) 
{
    if ( self::char( $data ) === '0' && substr( $data, 1, 1 ) != ':' ) {
        self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Invalid string length, leading zero' );
    }
    if ( ! $colon = @strpos( $data, ':' ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Invalid string length, colon not found' );
    }
    $length = intval( substr( $data, 0, $colon ) );
    if ( $length + $colon + 1 > strlen( $data ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Invalid string, input too short for string length' );
    }
    $string = substr( $data, $colon + 1, $length );
    $data = substr( $data, $colon + $length + 1 );
    return $string;
}

/** Decode torrent integer
 * @param string data to decode
 * @return integer decoded integer
 */
static private function decode_integer ( & $data ) 
{
    $start  = 0;
    $end    = strpos( $data, 'e');
    if ( $end === 0 )
        self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Empty integer' );
    if ( self::char( $data ) == '-' )
        $start++;
    if ( substr( $data, $start, 1 ) == '0' && ( $start != 0 || $end > $start + 1 ) )
        self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Leading zero in integer' );
    if ( ! ctype_digit( substr( $data, $start, $end ) ) )
        self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Non-digit characters in integer' );
    $integer = substr( $data, 0, $end );
    $data = substr( $data, $end + 1 );
    return $integer + 0;
}

/** Helper to return the first char of encoded data
 * @param string encoded data
 * @return string|boolean first char of encoded data or false if empty data
 */
static private function char ( $data ) 
{
    return empty( $data ) ?
        false : 
        substr( $data, 0, 1 );
}

/**** Make BitTorrent ****/

/** Getter and setter of torrent annouce url
 * @param null|string annouce url (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return string|null annouce url or null if not set
 */
public function announce ( $announce = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $announce ) ?
        isset( $this->announce ) ? $this->announce : null :
        $this->touch( $this->announce = (string) $announce );
}

/** Getter and setter of torrent annouce list
 * @param null|array annouce list (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return array|null annouce list or null if not set
 */
public function announce_list ( $announce_list = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $announce_list ) ?
        isset( $this->{'announce-list'} ) ? $this->{'announce-list'} : null :
        $this->touch( $this->{'announce-list'} = (array) $announce_list );
}

/** Getter and setter of torrent comment
 * @param null|string comment (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return string|null comment or null if not set
 */
public function comment ( $comment = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $comment ) ?
        isset( $this->comment ) ? $this->comment : null :
        $this->touch( $this->comment = (string) $comment );
}

/** Getter and setter of torrent name
 * @param null|string name (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return string|null name or null if not set
 */
public function name ( $name = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $name ) ?
        isset( $this->info['name'] ) ? $this->info['name'] : null :
        $this->touch( $this->info['name'] = (string) $name );
}

/** Getter and setter of private flag
 * @param null|boolean is private or not (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return boolean private flag
 */
public function is_private ( $private = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $private ) ?
        ! empty( $this->info['private'] ) :
        $this->touch( $this->info['private'] = $private ? 1 : 0 );
}

/** Getter and setter of webseed(s) url list ( GetRight implementation )
 * @param null|string|array webseed or webseeds mirror list (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return string|array|null webseed(s) or null if not set
 */
public function url_list ( $urls = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $urls ) ?
        isset( $this->{'url-list'} ) ? $this->{'url-list'} : null :
        $this->touch( $this->{'url-list'} = $urls );
}

/** Getter and setter of httpseed(s) url list ( Bittornado implementation )
 * @param null|string|array httpseed or httpseeds mirror list (optional, if omitted it's a getter)
 * @return array|null httpseed(s) or null if not set
 */
public function httpseeds ( $urls = null ) 
{
    return is_null( $urls ) ?
        isset( $this->httpseeds ) ? $this->httpseeds : null :
        $this->touch( $this->httpseeds = (array)  $urls );
}

/** Save torrent file to disk
 * @param null|string name of the file (optional)
 * @return boolean file has been saved or not
 */
public function save ( $filename = null ) 
{
    return file_put_contents( is_null( $filename ) ? $this->info['name'] . '.torrent' : $filename, $this );
}

/** Send torrent file to client
 * @param null|string name of the file (optional)
 * @return void script exit
 */
public function send ( $filename = null ) 
{
    $data = (string) $this;
    header( 'Content-type: application/x-bittorrent' );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $data ) );
    header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', $this->{'creation date'} ) . ' GMT');
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ( is_null( $filename ) ? $this->info['name'] . '.torrent' : $filename ) . '"' );
    exit( $data );
}

/** Build torrent info
 * @param string|array source folder/file(s) path
 * @param integer piece length
 * @return array|boolean torrent info or false if data isn't folder/file(s)
 */
protected function build ( $data, $piece_length ) 
{
    if ( is_null( $data ) )
        return false;
    elseif ( is_array( $data ) && self::is_list( $data ) )
        return $this->info = $this->files( $data, $piece_length );
    elseif ( is_dir( $data ) )
        return $this->info = $this->folder( $data, $piece_length );
    elseif ( is_file( $data ) && pathinfo( $data, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) != 'torrent' )
        return $this->info = $this->file( $data, $piece_length );
    else
        return false;
}

/** Build torrent info from single file
 * @param string file path
 * @param integer piece length
 * @return array torrent info
 */
private function file ( $file, $piece_length ) 
{
    if ( ! $handle = self::fopen( $file, $size = self::filesize( $file ) ) ) {
        return ! self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Failed to open file: "' . $file . '"' );
    }
    $pieces = '';
    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
        $pieces .= self::pack( fread( $handle, $piece_length ) );
    fclose( $handle );
    return array(
        'length'        => $size,
        'name'          => basename( $file ),
        'piece length'  => $piece_length,
        'pieces'        => $pieces
    );
}

/** Build torrent info from files
 * @param array file list
 * @param integer piece length
 * @return array torrent info
 */
private function files ( $files, $piece_length ) 
{
    $files  = array_map( 'realpath', $files );
    sort( $files );
    usort( $files, create_function( '$a,$b', 'return strrpos($a,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)-strrpos($b,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);' ) );
    $path   = explode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, dirname( realpath( current( $files ) ) ) );
    $length = $piece_length;
    $piece  = $pieces = '';
    foreach ( $files as $i => $file ) {
        if ( $path != array_intersect_assoc( $file_path = explode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file ), $path ) ) {
         self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Files must be in the same folder: "' . $file . '" discarded' );
            continue;
        }
        if ( ! $handle = self::fopen( $file, $filesize = self::filesize( $file ) ) ) {
         self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Failed to open file: "' . $file . '" discarded' );
            continue;
        }
        while ( ! feof( $handle ) ) {
            if ( ( $length = strlen( $piece .= fread( $handle, $length ) ) ) == $piece_length ) {
                $pieces .= self::pack( $piece );
            } else {
                $length = $piece_length - $length;
            }
        }
        fclose( $handle );
        $info_files[$i] = array(
            'length'    => $filesize,
            'path'      => array_diff( $file_path, $path )
        );
    }
    switch ( count( $info_files ) ) {
        case 0:
            return false;
        case 1:
            return $this->file( $files[key( $info_files )], $piece_length );
        default:
            return array(
                'files'         => $info_files,
                'name'          => end( $path ),
                'piece length'  => $piece_length,
                'pieces'        => $pieces . ( $piece ? self::pack( $piece ) : '' )
            );
    }
}

/** Build torrent info from folder content
 * @param string folder path
 * @param integer piece length
 * @return array torrent info
 */
private function folder ( $dir, $piece_length ) {
    return $this->files( self::scandir( $dir ), $piece_length );
}

/** Set torrent creator and creation date
 * @return void
 */
protected function touch () {
    $this->{'created by'}       = 'Torrent PHP Class - Adrien Gibrat';
    $this->{'creation date'}    = time();
}

/** Helper to return filesize (even bigger than 2Gb, linux only)
 * @param string file path
 * @return double|boolean filesize or false if error
 */
static public function filesize ( $file ) {
    return ( $size = @filesize( $file ) ) !== false ?
        (double) sprintf( '%u', $size ) :
        false;
}

/** Helper to open file to read (even bigger than 2Gb, linux only)
 * @param string file path
 * @param integer|double file size (optional)
 * @return ressource|boolean file handle or false if error
 */
static public function fopen ( $file, $size = null ) {
    if ( ( is_null( $size ) ? self::filesize( $file ) : $size )  <= 2 * pow( 1024, 3 ) )
        return fopen( $file, 'r' );
    elseif ( PHP_OS != 'Linux' )
        return ! self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'File size is greater than 2GB. This is only supported under Linux' );
    elseif ( ! is_readable( $file ) )
        return false;
    else
        return popen( 'cat ' . escapeshellarg( realpath( $file ) ), 'r' );
}

/** Helper scan directories files and sub directories recursivly
 * @param string directory path
 * @return array directory content list
 */
static public function scandir ( $dir ) {
    $paths = array();
    foreach ( scandir( $dir ) as $item  )
            if ( $item != '.' && $item != '..' )
                if ( is_dir( $path = realpath( $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item ) ) )
                    $paths = array_merge( self::scandir( $path ), $paths );
                else
                    $paths[] = $path;
    return $paths;
}

/** Helper to pack data hash
 * @param string data
 * @return string packed data hash
 */
static protected function pack ( & $data ) {
    return pack('H*', sha1( $data ) ) . ( $data = '' );
}

/**** Analyze BitTorrent ****/

/** Get piece length
 * @return integer piece length or null if not set
 */
public function piece_length () {
    return isset( $this->info['piece length'] ) ?
        $this->info['piece length'] :
        null;
}

/** Compute hash info
 * @return string hash info or null if info not set
 */
public function hash_info () {
    return isset( $this->info ) ? 
        sha1( self::encode( $this->info ) ) : 
        null;
}

/** List torrent content
 * @param integer|null size precision (optional, if omitted returns sizes in bytes)
 * @return array file(s) and size(s) list, files as keys and sizes as values
 */
public function content ( $precision = null ) {
    $files = array();
    if ( is_array( $this->info['files'] ) )
        foreach ( $this->info['files'] as $file )
            $files[self::path( $file['path'], $this->info['name'] )] = $precision ? 
                self::format( $file['length'], $precision ) : 
                $file['length'];
    elseif ( isset( $this->info['name'] ) )
            $files[$this->info['name']] = $precision ? 
                self::format( $this->info['length'], $precision ) : 
                $this->info['length'];
    return $files;
}

/** List torrent content pieces and offset(s)
 * @return array file(s) and pieces/offset(s) list, file(s) as keys and pieces/offset(s) as values
 */
public function offset () {
    $files = array();
    $size = 0;
    if ( is_array( $this->info['files'] ) )
        foreach ( $this->info['files'] as $file )
            $files[self::path( $file['path'], $this->info['name'] )] = array(
                'startpiece'    => floor( $size / $this->info['piece length'] ),
                'offset'        => fmod( $size, $this->info['piece length'] ),
                'size'          => $size += $file['length'],
                'endpiece'      => floor( $size / $this->info['piece length'] )
            );
    elseif ( isset( $this->info['name'] ) )
            $files[$this->info['name']] = array(
                'startpiece'    => 0,
                'offset'        => 0,
                'size'          => $this->info['length'],
                'endpiece'      => floor( $this->info['length'] / $this->info['piece length'] )
            );
    return $files;
}

/** Sum torrent content size
 * @param integer|null size precision (optional, if omitted returns size in bytes)
 * @return integer|string file(s) size
 */
public function size ( $precision = null ) {
    $size = 0;
    if ( is_array( $this->info['files'] ) )
        foreach ( $this->info['files'] as $file )
            $size += $file['length'];
    elseif ( isset( $this->info['name'] ) )
            $size = $this->info['length'];
    return is_null( $precision ) ? 
        $size :
        self::format( $size, $precision );
}

/** Request torrent statistics from scrape page
 * @param string announce or scrape page url (optional, to request an alternative tracker BUT mandatory for static call)
 * @param string torrent hash info (optional: ONLY for static call)
 * @return array tracker torrent statistics
 */
/* static */ public function scrape ( $announce = null, $hash_info = null ) {
    if ( ! ini_get( 'allow_url_fopen' ) )
        return ! self::$errors[] = new Exception( '"allow_url_fopen" must be enabled' );
    $packed_hash = pack('H*', $hash_info ? $hash_info : sha1( self::encode( $this->info ) ) );
    $scrape_data = file_get_contents( str_ireplace( '/announce', '/scrape', $announce ? $announce : $this->announce ) . '?info_hash=' . urlencode( $packed_hash ) );
    $stats = self::decode_data( $scrape_data );
    return isset( $stats['files'][$packed_hash] ) ?
        $stats['files'][$packed_hash] :
        ! self::$errors[] = new Exception( 'Invalid scrape data' );
}

/** Helper to build file path
 * @param array file path
 * @param string base folder
 * @return string real file path
 */
static private function path ( $path, $folder ) {
    array_unshift( $path, $folder );
    return join( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path );
}

/** Helper to format size in bytes to human readable
 * @param integer size in bytes
 * @param integer precision after coma
 * @return string formated size in appropriate unit
 */
static public function format ( $size, $precision = 2 ) {
    $units = array ('octets', 'Ko', 'Mo', 'Go', 'To');
    while( ( $next = next( $units ) ) && $size > 1024 )
        $size /= 1024;
    return round( $size, $precision ) . ' ' . ( $next ? prev( $units ) : end( $units ) );
}

}
```

And here how i am Calling it:

```
$torrent = new Torrent( './ammyy.admin.v3.torrent' );
echo '<br>private: ', $torrent->is_private() ? 'yes' : 'no', 
     '<br>annonce: ', $torrent->announce(), 
     '<br>name: ', $torrent->name(), 
     '<br>comment: ', $torrent->comment(), 
     '<br>piece_length: ', $torrent->piece_length(), 
     '<br>size: ', $torrent->size( 2 ),
     '<br>hash info: ', $torrent->hash_info(),
     '<br>stats: ';
var_dump( $torrent->scrape() );
echo '<br>content: ';
var_dump( $torrent->content() );
echo '<br>source: ',
     $torrent;
```

here is my out put:

```
private: no
annonce: udp://tracker.ccc.de:80/announce
name: files
comment: Torrent downloaded from torrent cache at http://torcache.net/
piece_length: 32768
size: 726.27 Ko
hash info: cab06d97573a62ba6fadebd183ae7e85c759b31f
stats: 
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "udp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php on line 661

Warning: file_get_contents(udp://tracker.ccc.de:80/scrape?info_hash=%CA%B0m%97W%3Ab%BAo%AD%EB%D1%83%AE%7E%85%C7Y%B3%1F): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php on line 661

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid string length, colon not found' in J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php:272 Stack trace: #0 J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php(212): Torrent::decode_string(false) #1 J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php(662): Torrent::decode_data(false) #2 J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php(703): Torrent->scrape() #3 {main} thrown in J:\Soft\portables\platform\PortableApps\server\App\server\doc_root\torrent downloader\editTorrent.php on line 272
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: There is no such wrapper - http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php The problem with UDP is that in case of TCP you have a tunnel, inside of which all data goes in both directions, but in case of UDP you send the UDP packet and have to open the port to listen for the answer (if it would come back). And if you get some data back, the packets can return in different order - you have to deal with this too.

Comment: There is one  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/transports.inet.php

Comment: Please post only relevant parts of code.

Comment: @MasumNishat it is for the streams, not for the way you are trying to use it (not for the `file_get_contents`). Read and look at examples - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php

Comment: actully i dident created the code

Comment: LICENSE: This source file is subject to version 3 of the GNU GPL
 * that is available through the world-wide-web at the following URI:
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.  If you did not receive a copy of
 * the GNU GPL License and are unable to obtain it through the web, please
 * send a note to adrien.gibrat@gmail.com so I can mail you a copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing with PHP's mix of 'streams' and 'sockets', but there's difference between the two.

A stream wrapper/protocol is something that you can work with *as if* it is a file. You can use stream wrappers with `file_get_contents()` or any of the filesystem-related functions.

The supported wrappers are listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Socket transports are a different thing and operate on a lower level. Other than the possibility for a connection to be closed, they don't have size boundaries and can be infinite. You can't read infinity with `file_get_contents()`.

The supported socket transport are listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/transports.php

'udp://' is a socket transport and you can't read it with `file_get_contents()`.

However, stream wrappers *can* sit on top of socket transports, simply because they operate on different network layers. So technically, you *could* write and register a custom wrapper around a UDP socket (and in this case, you should name it 'torrent://') via [stream_wrapper_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php), but that requires more in-depth knowledge about network protocols.